# jQuery redirect - fadeout/fadein

Tags: jquery, redirect, fadein, fadeout

I'm working on a redirect script in jQuery. This is my script so far;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
   window.location.href = "http://test.example.com/;"
  }, 5000);
});
```

This script will redirect after 5 seconds as I want to. What I'm trying to do is to fadeout the page before redirect and then fadein the new document. Is this possible to do?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
 $(function(){
    $("body").fadeOut(1000,function(){
       window.location.href = "http://test.example.com/;"
    })
 });
```

On the new page just write:

```
 $(function(){
    $("body").hide();
    $("body").fadeIn(1000);
 })
```

This will fade out the entire page by the `body` element.

On your new page it will initially hide the `body` then fade it in.

In fact you could make this a global thing with an event listener like this:

```
 $(window).bind('unload', function(){
   ....
 });
```

If you wanted this whole thing to start 60 seconds after the page loads you could do this:

```
 $(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").fadeOut(1000,function(){
           window.location.href = "http://test.example.com/;"
        })
    },60000)
 });
```

Comment: Cool! That helps a bit, but how can I make the redirect with this script to start after 60 seconds? With this code it starts the redirect instantly...

Comment: @zorensen What do you mean? Wouldn't you want a redirect after someone clicks something? You are saying you want to redirect the user 60 seconds after they get to the page?

Comment: There we go! That worked perfectly :) Thanks for the help @Johnston!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a mask?

Make a div, position it with css on top of your page and it's width and height to match the document width and height (or whatever width and height you need). Then just fade that in and out.